# Find an equation for the surface with all points which are equidistant of $(-1,0,0)$ and the plane $x=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find an equation for the surface with all points which are equidistant of $(-1,0,0)$ and the plane $x=1$. Draw the surface.

First, this is the graph I've depicted:

[image: Point (-1,0,0) and x=1]

Some ideas to find such equation and the corresponding graph for the surface?

Comment: Given a point $(x,y,z)$, can you find its distance to $(-1,0,0)$ and to the plane? And can you equate those two distances?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The distance from $(x,y,z)$ to the plane is simply $|x-1|$, and the distance from $(x,y,z)$ to $(-1,0,0)$ is $\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2+z^2}$. Setting the two equal to eah other, we get

$$(x-1)^2 = (x+1)^2 + y^2 + z^2$$
$$-4x = y^2 + z^2$$
$$x = -\frac{1}{4}(y^2+z^2)$$

Comment: why do you equal both distances?

Comment: Because a given point on the surface will be equidistant from the plane and $(-1,0,0)$, by definition that means the distances will be equal.

Answer (score 2):

If $z$ is not considered standard a 2D definition of parabola can be obtained by setting equal distances as:

$$x = -\frac{y^2}{4} $$

So with z considered it becomes a 3D generalized surface of revolution as a paraboloid rotated about $x$ axis vertically up  :

$$ (x,y,z) = (-2,2,2)$$

$$x = -\frac{y^2+z^2}{4} $$

$ yz $ plane is horizontal, $x$ axis is vertical as shown.

[image: Paraboloid]

Comment: so does the graph look like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/1r2hp9owr6tok6i/Taller%20No.%202%20-%201.png?dl=0 ?

Comment: No, as shown above.